# Modifying Option Bytes at compile time

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, firmware, c++

I need to modify the option bytes at compile time for STM32L0xx controller and generate the binaries i.e. .hex, .bin. could you please suggest a solution for the same. I amusing STM32Cube IDE for development in C

Comment: This isn't really part of the compilation phase, but rather part of the chip programming phase.  See the manual of whatever software you are using to program the chip, setting option bytes is *not* the same as loading flash contents; it's possible that some software might recognize option byte values in a .hex file (as they do have addresses) and program them using the appropriate unique programming sequence (vs the usual one for program flash), but you cannot assume that.  Cube is an IDE, you need to look at the software used to actually flash the chip.

Comment: eg, one of my projects is set up such that in addition to a target to flash the firmware, the Makefile has a target that runs a bunch of explicit OpenOCD-unique commands to set the option bytes.  As the firmware itself implements an A/B upgrade scheme, it will also check the option bytes and fix them and restart if they are not as needed.

Comment: I have the same question and it seems that STM32 parts just don't support this in any meaningful way. With other manufacturers you can just put the fuse bytes in the .hex file and they can be programmed with the various tools, but there is nothing like that for STM32.